# How to use pretty urls in Kendo UI Mobile app?

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui

By default navigation is done by `app.navigate('#view-id')` and it rewrites hash to `/#view-id`. If I want to add some params it becomes `/#view-id?key=val`.

I would like to use kendo.Router class and make url look like `/key/val` or `/#key/val`

I can define `kendo.Router()` routes but how can I switch views without using `app.navigate`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check my reply in your other question. This is not supported currently, but it should be easy to implement in case you are willing to dive into the internals of the mobile app implementation.